# What's the FFT2 of white noise image?

Tags: image-processing, fft, discrete-signals, noise, random-process

I try to compute the **FFT2** of the **white noise image**.

I use this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:White-noise-mv255-240x180.png)
with Entropy 7.995 and
pixel scatter plot:

[image]

based on this python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread("White_noise.png")
image = image - np.mean(image)
ft = np.fft.ifftshift(image)
ft = np.fft.fft2(ft)
ft = np.fft.fftshift(ft)
res = ft/ np.max(ft)
res = np.sqrt(abs(res.flatten()))

plt.hist(res, bins= 50)
plt.show
```

I get this:

[image]

Why something like that happens? can someone explain it mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia page says:

> A "white noise" grayscale image. Each sample is a pseudo-random
> integer in the range 0..255, chosen with uniform distribution. The
> choices are "independent" to the extent that the outputs of the
> pseudo-random number are assumed to be. Image created by J. Stolfi
> with a C program.

So the original distribution is a uniform distribution.

[The 2D FFT is just:](https://www.corsi.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid027832.pdf)
$$
F[k,l] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} I(n,m) e^{-j 2\pi (k m / M + l n / N)}
$$
so each pixel in the FFT is the sum of many pixels.

When you sum many random values of *just about* any distribution, the resulting distribution will be Gaussian due to the [central limit theorem.](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_probability/BS704_Probability12.html#:%7E:text=The%20central%20limit%20theorem%20states,will%20be%20approximately%20normally%20distributed.)

That's why the distribution you see is normal or Gaussian.

I just noticed that you've taken the square root. In that case, [you'll find the distribution more complicated.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/527262/5965)

Comment: Thanks, the existence of a square root guarantees normal distribution with a mean of around 0.5
without a square root, I have something like that: [link](ibb.co/5KPQX81)  ------ 
 Is there a relationship between the entropy of the original image (any image, not just white noise) and the output of the 2D Fourier transform?

Comment: @user64854 I don't think there's a clear relationship between entropy and the DFT.  Yes, the absolute value you take of the Fourier coefficients will cause the distribution to be $\chi^2$, which is why the square root "fixes" it.

Answer (score 0):

While real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform of white noise are distributed
normally (because of the Central Limit Theorem, as mentioned in another answer), the
absolute value is *not*. It's distribution has CDF of the form:
$$
f_1(x) = axe^{-bx^2}
$$
where $a,b$ are some constants.

If you take square root of that random variable you will get a distribution which looks
``more normal'', but it is not normal. Its CDF  can be represented as
$$
f_2(x) = ax^2 e^{-bx^4}
$$

Here are the graphs of both CDFs:
[image: CDFs]

And here are the histograms of the FFT's components from a pseudo-random 2D white noise:

[image: Histograms of FFTs]

The script which generated the above histograms:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nn = 512;
x = np.random.rand (nn,nn)- 0.5;
f =  (np.fft.fft2 (x)).flatten ();
fReal = np.real (f);
fImag = np.imag (f);
fAbs  = np.abs (f);

fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,3, figsize=(9,3));
ax[0].hist (fReal, bins=64);
ax[1].hist (fImag, bins=64);
ax[2].hist (fAbs, bins=64);
ax[0].set_title ("FFT Imag");
ax[1].set_title ("FFT Real");
ax[2].set_title ("FFT Abs");
# plt.grid ();
plt.show ();
```